# How to plot python pyviz network nodes

Tags: python, treeview

I am using python pyvis package for nodes visualization. Is it pyvis tree can only render on separate html? can't we plot using matplotlib package?

```
from pyvis.network import Network
import pandas as pd

got_net = Network(height="750px", width="100%", bgcolor="#222222", font_color="white")

# set the physics layout of the network
got_net.barnes_hut()
got_data = pd.read_csv("https://www.macalester.edu/~abeverid/data/stormofswords.csv")

sources = got_data['Source']
targets = got_data['Target']
weights = got_data['Weight']

edge_data = zip(sources, targets, weights)

for e in edge_data:
    src = e[0]
    dst = e[1]
    w = e[2]

    got_net.add_node(src, src, title=src)
    got_net.add_node(dst, dst, title=dst)
    got_net.add_edge(src, dst, value=w)

neighbor_map = got_net.get_adj_list()

# add neighbor data to node hover data
for node in got_net.nodes:
    node["title"] += " Neighbors:<br>" + "<br>".join(neighbor_map[node["id"]])
    node["value"] = len(neighbor_map[node["id"]])

got_net.show("gameofthrones.html")
```

In the above code, nodes are rendering in separate html on new browser tab, I want to plot them instead of HTML something like

```
plt.plot(got_net)
```

I appreciate if anyone can help to understand this package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [pyviz documentation](https://pyvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#using-pyvis-within-jupyter-notebook) you can set the optional parameter `notebook` to `True` in the `Network` constructor, and if you're in a jupyter notebook it will display it:

```
got_net = Network(
    height="750px", 
    width="100%", 
    bgcolor="#222222", 
    font_color="white", 
    notebook=True # here
)
...
got_net.show("gameofthrones.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `notebook = True` in the `Network` constructor then adding this as follows resolved the issue for my implementation:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

...

got_net.show("gameofthrones.html")

display(HTML("gameofthrones.html"))
```